# Css default border gets removed

Tags: jquery

A validation page , if the entered data is wrong,then it has to focus to that input element and gives that element(dropdowntextbox) with a red border,Once user enters right input the red border should be removed,so I have used border:none to remove the red border;now what happens is the default border of  textbox also gets removed.What should i do

Comment: ...and possibly your css?

Comment: .css("border":"1px solid red");  when entered data is wrong             .css("border","none")-once error is removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use

border:your default boder;

instead of

border:none

```
.css("border":"1px solid your default color");
```